# Executing perl via cgid on solaris fails in 64 bit, but works in 32 bit

Tags: apache, perl, 64-bit, cgi, solaris

I have a custom build of apache's `httpd` version 2.2 together with `perl` version 5.22 on solaris 10. The httpd runs in a chroot environment, and the perl script is executed via httpd's `mod_cgid`. So far all was in 32 bit things worked. Now I have compiled everything in 64 bit (because another httpd module is only provided as a 64 bit binary), and now I cannot get the perl script to be executed via cgid.

The http error log contains the line

```
Premature end of script headers.
```

So I tried to execute my test script without cgid, just using perl inside the chroot, and besides some warnings it just worked fine. Here is my script, if its of any interest:

```
#!/local/perl5/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
opendir(DIRHANDLE, "/");
@filenames = readdir(DIRHANDLE);
foreach $file (@filenames) { print "$file\n"; }
closedir(DIRHANDLE);
```

(I know its not a great one :))

The warnings were about the locale not being set, so I fixed that by adding `/usr/lib/locale` to the chroot. This fixed the warnings, but did not fix the original problem. So I assume this was not the root cause. Even more so, when I compared to the 32 bit build, I got the same warnings, however the script would execute fine via cgid.

Next thing I did was to trace the systemcalls via `truss -f -o mylogfile.txt`. The full output can be found [on pastebin (32 bit truss)](https://pastebin.com/k2ZsWDbx). Here is an excerpt for the **32** bit build (line 4296 on pastebin) - note that paths are not exactly the same as on pastebin, but the observed result is the same:

```
28420:  sigaction(SIGCLD, 0xFFBFF6A8, 0xFFBFF748)       = 0
28420:  chdir("/path/to/my/chroot/cgi-bin/") = 0
28420:  execve("/path/to/my/chroot/cgi-bin/test.pl", 0x00183DB8, 0x00183570)  argc = 3
28420:      *** SUID: ruid/euid/suid = 50001 / 50001 / 50001  ***
28420:      *** SGID: rgid/egid/sgid = 50001 / 50001 / 50001  ***
28420:  sysinfo(SI_MACHINE, "sun4u", 257)               = 6
```

And here is the [truss output](https://pastebin.com/iBhmyYgh) for the **64** bit build. The following is an excerpt (line 4489), note I left out some lines, denoted by `[...]`:

```
28906/21:       open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)                  = 12
[...]
28911:  sigaction(SIGCLD, 0xFFFFFFFF7FFFF150, 0xFFFFFFFF7FFFF250) = 0
28911:  chdir("/path/to/my/chroot/cgi-bin/") = 0
28906/21:       pollsys(0xFFFFFFFF747F7080, 1, 0xFFFFFFFF747F6FA0, 0x00000000) = 1
28906/21:       read(12, 0x10034BB38, 8000)                     = 0
28906/21:       close(12)                                       = 0
[...]
28906/21:       read(10, "\0\0 pEF", 4)                         = 4
28906/21:       kill(28911, SIGTERM)                            Err#3 ESRCH
28904:  close(4)                                        = 0
```

As Andrew Haenle noticed, I did not execute the same scripts in 32 bit vs 64 bit - at least in the truss output shown above. So here is the truss output for the failing 64 bit, where I execute the same script as in 32 bit: https://pastebin.com/Nz1jBjne

Here is some more truss output from the 64 bit build, with the additional flags `-a -e -d`: https://pastebin.com/4NMGD2aR

The way I interpret this is that after changing to the cgi-bin directory, cgid gets killed in 64 bit, vs. executing the script in 32 bit. 
Permissions are the same, so I do not see what is the problem here. At least it explains the message from the error log - since the script is not executed, no headers are ever printed.

Anyway, I am a bit lost where to go from here. Any hints how to debug this further would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does /local/perl5/bin/perl exist in the chroot jail?

Comment: Yes, of course :) It does not only exist, I have explicitly executed and verified its functionality in the chroot.

Comment: The `read()` on file descriptor 12 returns 0 (EOF). Can you find out what the descriptor is pointing to? And does it work outside of the chroot jail?

Comment: @GuidoFlohr How would I find out what the descriptor is pointing to? As for if it works outside the chroot - I need to think how I can test that, because everything around it is built for being executed only inside the chroot.

Comment: @Isaac The 12 must be the result of a prior call to `open()`. And do you know what the two PIDs are? 28911 is probably your worker and 28906 its parent process? And - probably a stupid suggestion - where does the trailling slash after "/chroot/cgi-bin/" come from? If it's a config file, try removing it.

Comment: That error message `Premature end of script headers` suggests that no output is being provided by the script, as a print statement is the first thing in the script I suggest that the script hasn't actually been run. Can you add the command line parameters you passed to truss.

Comment: Note the lack of `exec` in the 64-bit version. What happens between the `chdir` and the `exec` in the source?

Comment: @GuidoFlohr I have added the `open()` call for descriptor 12 (`/dev/urandom`). I assume the PIDs are as follows: 28911 is the cgid, and 28906 is an apache worker.  @JGNI I have added the truss parameters (`-f -o logfile`). And I agree with your analysis, the script has not run, the question is why.

Comment: I can now confirm my assumption about the PIDs.

Comment: @ikegami Interesting question. How would I find out? The C source does not have the `chdir` and `execve` in the source code, so I assume these are compiler generated machine instructions (?).

Comment: Something seems to be missing from the posted `truss` output.  First, given `open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)`, I don't think `read(12, 0x10034BB38, 8000)` should return 0.  Second, `8000` is an awfully large number of bytes to read from `/dev/urandom`.  Third, the `read(12, 0x10034BB38, 8000)` returning `0` happens immediately after `pollsys(0xFFFFFFFF747F7080, 1, 0xFFFFFFFF747F6FA0, 0x00000000) = 1`.  There'd be no need to poll `/dev/urandom` in the first place, and it wouldn't return an `EOF` condition should it poll as active - there'd be data to read.

Comment: What did you configure `ScriptSock` to be? Could there be a problem with opening the socket? And do you really have to use a threaded mpm and mod_cgid (instead of plain mod_cgi)?

Comment: @AndrewHenle You are right, those were just excerpts from the truss output. I have added links to pastebin for the complete output

Comment: @GuidoFlohr threaded mpm and mod_cgid (instead of cgi) is a customer requirement.I need to check that `ScriptSock` thingy - however I would have expected an error for opening the socket, if that would be the problem.

Comment: The call to `sigaction(SIGCLD, ...)` comes from https://github.com/apache/apr/blob/trunk/threadproc/unix/proc.c#L471. The next system call is `chdir()`, It then looks like it has to continue with `geteuid()` in line 481 but that was a little different in httpd-2.2. The only interesthing happening before the final call (@ikegami: your question) to `execve()` is then a call to `limit_proc()` which should actually trigger a call to `setrlimit()` but I cannot see that in your truss output. Still, could resource limits be the problem? And what is the 3rd process with pid 28904?

Comment: @Isaac try to add some printf debugging after the call to `apr_signal()` and `chdir()`. But you have to be aware that that code is not only called from mod_cgid(). If you prefix the log output with `progname`, you should probably see whether it's the cgi stuff being executed.

Comment: @GuidoFlohr I will give that printf debugging a shot  - thank you for pointing out the correct place in the source code, I would not have found that. It will take me a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thank you to all who have made comments and suggestions.

Finally it turns out that it was a permissions problem. Not in the script, but in the libraries. The way my chroot environment is built is that it gets is custom permissions applied inside the chroot. Now that mechanism was not yet adapted to 64 bit. 64 bit libraries live in different subdirectories of the standard locations for 32 bit backwards compatibility. Also, my httpd process runs as a non-root user. After correcting the permissions perl worked like a charm in 64 bit.

But maybe more interesting for the general public is how I found this out: I added the `-X` flag to the apache startup command. That enables debug mode for apache, and finally produced the error message I needed:

```
env.pl: Cannot execute /lib/sparcv9/ld.so.1
cgi-test.cgi: Cannot execute /lib/sparcv9/ld.so.1
```

After executing - inside the chroot of course -

```
chmod o+x /lib/sparcv9/ld.so.1
chmod o+r /lib/sparcv9/*
```

my perl test scripts worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Your 32- and 64-bit tests are not the same.  Per the posted `truss` output, the 32-bit process appears to run a Perl CGI script called `cgi-test.cgi`:

```
28415/25:   stat64("/local/content/apache/myinstance.acme.com/cgi-bin/cgi-test.cgi", 0xFAFFBA18) = 0
28415/25:   lstat64("/local", 0xFAFFBA18)           = 0
28415/25:   lstat64("/local/content", 0xFAFFBA18)       = 0
28415/25:   lstat64("/local/content/apache", 0xFAFFBA18)    = 0
28415/25:   lstat64("/local/content/apache/myinstance.acme.com", 0xFAFFBA18) = 0
28415/25:   lstat64("/local/content/apache/myinstance.acme.com/cgi-bin", 0xFAFFBA18) = 0
28415/25:   lstat64("/local/content/apache/myinstance.acme.com/cgi-bin/cgi-test.cgi", 0xFAFFBA18) = 0
28415/25:   open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)          = 12
28415/25:   read(12, "C3 E DB1 A03 5 kCBA8DF\r".., 64)  = 64
28415/25:   close(12)                   = 0
28415/25:   open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)          = 12
28415/25:   read(12, "E6 L _F3 uBC fA7E18AFC \".., 64)  = 64
28415/25:   close(12)                   = 0
28415/25:   so_socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, "", SOV_DEFAULT) = 12
28415/25:   connect(12, 0xFAFF7AA8, 110, SOV_DEFAULT)  
 ...
28420:  sigaction(SIGCLD, 0xFFBFF6A8, 0xFFBFF748)   = 0
28420:  chdir("/local/content/apache/myinstance.acme.com/cgi-bin/") = 0
28420:  execve("/local/content/apache/myinstance.acme.com/cgi-bin/cgi-test.cgi", 0x00183DB8, 0x00183570)  argc = 3
28420:      *** SUID: ruid/euid/suid = 50001 / 50001 / 50001  ***
28420:      *** SGID: rgid/egid/sgid = 50001 / 50001 / 50001  ***
```

Note that the CGI script is run by PID 28420, where PID 28415 appears to be the "controlling" process.

But for the 64-bit process, this is the corresponding output, with the CGI script being `test.pl`:

```
28906/21:   stat("/local/content/apache/myinstance.acme.com/cgi-bin/test.pl", 0xFFFFFFFF747FB3E0) = 0
28906/21:   lstat("/local", 0xFFFFFFFF747FB3E0)     = 0
28906/21:   lstat("/local/content", 0xFFFFFFFF747FB3E0) = 0
28906/21:   lstat("/local/content/apache", 0xFFFFFFFF747FB3E0) = 0
28906/21:   lstat("/local/content/apache/myinstance.acme.com", 0xFFFFFFFF747FB3E0) = 0
28906/21:   lstat("/local/content/apache/myinstance.acme.com/cgi-bin", 0xFFFFFFFF747FB3E0) = 0
28906/21:   lstat("/local/content/apache/myinstance.acme.com/cgi-bin/test.pl", 0xFFFFFFFF747FB3E0) = 0
28906/21:   open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)          = 12
28906/21:   read(12, "9C `9F9899 uAED9 `1CBE11".., 64)  = 64
28906/21:   close(12)                   = 0
28906/21:   open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)          = 12
28906/21:   read(12, "C2F8FC11C31D = ! V ; O =".., 64)  = 64
28906/21:   close(12)                   = 0
28906/21:   so_socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, "", SOV_DEFAULT) = 12
28906/21:   connect(12, 0xFFFFFFFF747F9560, 110, SOV_DEFAULT) = 0
...
28911:  sigaction(SIGCLD, 0xFFFFFFFF7FFFF150, 0xFFFFFFFF7FFFF250) = 0
28911:  chdir("/local/content/apache/myinstance.acme.com/cgi-bin/") = 0
```

Note the lack of an `execve()` call.  And then PID 28911 disappears until this:

```
28906/21:   kill(28911, SIGTERM)                Err#3 ESRCH
28906/21:   kill(28911, SIG#0)              Err#3 ESRCH
```

There's not only no `execve()` call that actually executes the Perl script, there's no PID 28911 any more.

The problem appears to be the `test.pl` script.  What are the permissions on the script?  What user/group owns it?  Does it have any ACLs attached?

Comment: I am sorry to have posted missleading truss output - put the script is not the problem. I have tested both script in 32 and 64 bit. Both work in 32 bit, both do not work in 64 bit. I shall provide more accurate trussoutput.

Comment: @Isaac What are your `truss` options?  Are you running `truss` as `root`?  Can you?

Comment: yes, truss is run as root. I run `truss -f -o outputfile.txt`. Here is the truss output for `cgi-test.cgi` in 64 bit: https://pastebin.com/Nz1jBjne

Comment: @Isaac  Add the `-a -e -d` flags to `truss`.  I suspect your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and/or `LD_PRELOAD` set of envvals are set wrong and the `execve()` is getting a `SIGKILL` when it fails.

Comment: @Isaac  That last looks the same as the earlier 64-bit output.

Comment: This looks like a huge problem: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/sparcv9:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/lib:/opt/csw/lib:/usr/sfw/lib` That's mixing both 32- and 64-bit libraries into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. See both https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/ld.so.1-1.html and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/E26506/chapter6-63352.html#scrolltoc. Also, do all those directories exist under the `/chroot/instances/myinstance.acme.com` directory used by `chroot`?

Comment: While I agree that my use of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is far from optimal, it is not the problem. I have completely unset it, but the problem persists :( Also, the same messed up `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does not disturb the 32 bit build.

Comment: @Isaac *While I agree that my use of LD_LIBRARY_PATH is far from optimal, **it is not the problem**.*  You can't know that, since you don't know why the CGI script doesn't run under the 64-bit process.